# How to remove trailing zeros with scientific notation when convert double to string?

Tags: c++

[**Live On Coliru**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/337585f2af2cd32e)

[**FormatFloat**](https://www.includehelp.com/golang/strconv-formatfloat-function-with-examples.aspx)

I try to implement one conversion of `Golang strconv.FormatFloat()` in C++.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

std::string convert_str(double d)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (d >= 0.0001)
    {
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4); // I know the precision, so this is fine
        ss << d;
        return ss.str();
    }
    else
    {
        ss << std::scientific;
        ss << d;
        return ss.str();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << convert_str(0.002) << std::endl; // 0.0020
    std::cout << convert_str(0.00001234560000) << std::endl; // 1.234560e-05
    std::cout << convert_str(0.000012) << std::endl; // 1.200000e-05

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.0020
1.234560e-05 // should be 1.23456e-05
1.200000e-05 // should be 1.2e-05
```

Question> How can I setup the output modifier so that the trailing zero doesn't show up?

> strconv.FormatFloat(num, 'e', -1, 64)
>
> The special precision value (-1) is used for the smallest number of
> digits necessary such that ParseFloat() will return f exactly.

Comment: Go ahead and convert as you're doing, but before you return the string make a separate pass to remove the redundant zeros.

Comment: Yes, I saw people do this but not sure whether this is the only way.

Comment: I'd probably get shot to pieces if I posted it as a **C++** answer, but the good old C `printf` format specifier, `%lg` will do the trick: `printf("%lg %lg\n", 0.00001234560000, 0.000012);` shows `1.23456e-05 1.2e-05`.

Comment: That's why I made a comment instead of an answer. I admit the possibility that someone knows better than I.

Comment: @AdrianMole the C++ standard leaves all the C baggage alone for a reason. No need to be ashamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of being <strike>heavily downvoted</strike> criticised for posting a **C** answer to a **C++** question ... you can use the `%lg` format specifier in a call to `sprintf`.

From [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> Unless alternative representation is requested the trailing zeros are
> removed, also the decimal point character is removed if no fractional
> part is left.

So, if you only want to remove the trailing zeros when using scientific notation, you can change your `convert_str` function to something like the following:

```cpp
std::string convert_str(double d)
{
    if (d >= 0.0001) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4); // I know the precision, so this is fine
        ss << d;
        return ss.str();
    }
    else {
        char cb[64];
        sprintf(cb, "%lg", d);
        return cb;
    }
}
```

For the three test cases in your code, this will give:

```
0.0020
1.23456e-05
1.2e-05
```

From C++20 and later, the [`std::format` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) may offer a more modern alternative; however, I'm not (yet) fully "up to speed" with that, so I cannot present a solution using it. Others may want to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, std::scientific don't remove trailing zeros from scientific notation. The good news, for your specific case, is that cout already format  values below 0.0001 using scientific notation, and removing trailing zeros. So you can let your code like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

std::string convert_str(double d)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (d >= 0.0001)
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4); // I know the precision, so this is fine

    ss << d;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << convert_str(0.002) << std::endl; // 0.0020
    std::cout << convert_str(0.00001234560000) << std::endl; // 1.23456e-05
    std::cout << convert_str(0.000012) << std::endl; // 1.2e-05
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wanted output can be generated with a combination of the [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`std::defaultfloat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) manipulators:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << std::defaultfloat
          << 0.002 << '\n'
          << 0.00001234560000 << '\n'
          << 0.000012 << '\n';
```

Live at: https://godbolt.org/z/67fWa1seo

Comment: The issue with setprecision is that it doesn't control the number of decimal after '.' https://godbolt.org/z/b9vq5Gxev

Comment: @q0987 No, but what does that have to do with the trailing zeroes? How would you want `100.00` to be represented?

Comment: 100.0. It seems that I just have to manually remove those trailing zeroes.

Comment: @q0987 Maybe. I don't understand why you don't consider it as a trailing zero. Is that how `strconv.FormatFloat` would format it?

Comment: just an application-specific requirement.

Comment: @q0987 Ok, could you please clarify these requirements in the question? Others may have more suitable suggestions.